# Set/Read cookies from subdomain to domain

Tags: php

I have to set cookies from subdomain to domain and I have to read them, how can I do it?

**Example:** sub1.domain.com -> domain.com

Thanks

Comment: Use `.domain.com` as domain when you set a cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.domain.com` as your domain (note the dot before `domain.com`). This way the cookie is available on all other subdomains, including the `www` subdomain.

Learn more about here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp